# Why is the query result truncated in email attachment when it is smaller than max file size?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sp-send-dbmail

I'm using a dynamic pivot query to create a table, which may have many many rows, and send this query result out by  msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail. It gives the correct results in MSSMS but when emailed the attachment is truncated. File size of the attachment is 65 KB and max file size is set to 10 MB.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
DECLARE @cols nVARCHAR(MAX),
@DynamicPivotQuery nVARCHAR(max);
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+ QUOTENAME(concatgrpQ) from test.dbo.unpivotedTable FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
N'
select *
into test.dbo.pivotedTable 
from 
(
  select *
  from test.dbo.unpivotedTable
) a
pivot
(
  max(Answer)
  for concatgrpQ in ('+@cols+')
) as p'

exec sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
--select * from test.dbo.pivotedTable;
declare @now as NVARCHAR(MAX)
set @now=convert(varchar, getdate(), 1)
declare @stringsubject as nVARCHAR(MAX)
set @stringsubject='Evaluation Export ' +@now+' -Automated DB email'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @profile_name = 'Gmail',  
    @recipients = 'test@test.com',  
    @body= 'open file as semi-colon delimited',
    @query = "select * from test.dbo.pivotedTable",  
    @subject = @stringsubject,
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @query_no_truncate = 1,
    @query_result_separator =';',
    @query_result_width=32767,
    @query_attachment_filename ='EvalExport.txt'

CREATE TABLE gngiadb.dbo.strcolnames (ColumnNames nvarchar(max))
declare @stringcolumnnames nvarchar(max)
set @stringcolumnnames= '"str1", "str2,"str3",str4", "str5"' +REPLACE(REPLACE(@cols, ']','"'),'[', '"');
INSERT INTO test.dbo.strcolnames
select @stringcolumnnames as 'ColumnNames'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @profile_name = 'Gmail',  
    @recipients = 'test@test.com',  
    @query= "select * from test.dbo.strcolnames",
    @body= @stringcolumnnames,
    @subject = 'column names comma-delimited- Automated DB email',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @query_result_header = 1,
    @query_no_truncate = 1,
    @query_result_width=32767,
    @query_attachment_filename ='ColumnNames.txt'
```

The actual emailed attachment is truncated at what seems to be a max of 65 KB.

Comment: Truncated columns, or rows?

Comment: depending on the results, it truncates in different places. The last row of the attachment is truncated in some place in the middle of the row (i.e., not all columns are populated), and the last value is present in its entirety. All rows following the truncated row are absent in the attachment.

Comment: Seems like there's a bug in MSSQLServer 2014 version on the server (version 12.0.2269). https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3004195/fix-sp-send-dbmail-stored-procedure-truncates-email-attachments-to-64

Comment: Nice catch. Apply the SP and see if it fixes it?

Comment: Thanks scsimon. I need to contact the ppl who set up the DBserver tomorrow to download and try.

Comment: You should add that as an answer also